# eclipse neon running with -clean removes all nebula updates and marketplace in helpmenu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace, nebula

eclipse neon running with -clean removes all nebula updates and marketplace in helpmenu

as described in some other thread, the workspace prompt does not show anymore when eclipse is started.
I run eclipse -clean and the workspace prompt is back.

But now the markeplace does no longer show in the help menu and all the installed nebula updates are gone.

Any hints?

Comment: you mention *some other thread*.  If you feel that thread is important them please provide a link to it.

Comment: i looked through to many threads searching for an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found out that the jre was corrupted:

i reinstalled eclipse from scratch, and still had problems.
the log pointed to some problem with the java vm

after i replaced the jre and completed the reinstallation of all the plugins and updates all is fine, even showing the marketplace in the help menu.

i can install from the marketplace only pulling the "install" from firefox into eclipse does not work... but might be an ubuntu problem